How to pass class objects between handlers in aiogram 3.11?
I'm writing a Telegram bot using aiogram 3.11. During the execution of my code, I create objects of a class, and I need to pass these objects between different handlers. I've been advised to look into middlewares, but I'm not sure how to implement this. Could someone explain the best way to share objects between handlers in aiogram 3.11? An example would be greatly appreciated.
I tried to use middlewares:
class InnerCallbackQueryUniqueClientMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
async def __call__(
    self,
    handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
    event: types.Message,
    data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
    user_data = UsersTable.get_or_none(UsersTable.tg_id == event.from_user.id)
    if user_data:
        tg_user = TgUser(
            tg_id=user_data.tg_id,
            name=user_data.name,
            surname=user_data.surname,
            username=user_data.username,
            confirm_code=user_data.confirm_code,
            is_attached=user_data.is_attached)
        data["tg_user"] = tg_user
    return await handler(event, data)

but handler:
@dp.message(StateFilter(State.START))
async def handler_button_activate(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, data: Dict[str, Any]):  
    pass

causes
TypeError: handler_button_activate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'


ok, let's think. you have a handler, that takes in 3 arguments (message, state and data). in your middleware you pass in 2 (event, data). what is missing?

as for your question - you pass a state variable into your handler. state is part of a storage (memory, redis, fs etc.), associated with user. depending on what you need you can use this storage by state.set_data() or state.get_data(). memory storage can be used to store classes (redis and fs - not). plus you still can use sqlite db to store something simple like provided user model - it is fast enough.
